# Executable jar does not run via command line

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt, executable-jar

I have created executable jar from my java project in eclipse. On double click it runs just fine, but via command line it returns some errors.
Tried:

```
c:\>myFile.jar
c:\>"myFile.jar"
c:\>java -jar myFile.jar  //here i can see the errors
```

[image] 
How can i run the file via cmd like I double clicked it?

Comment: Nope, we'd really like to see the error :-)

Comment: Can you post the returned errors?

Comment: What's the error?  If it's about a missing main class then you need a manifest.

Comment: I'd provide the answer, but I think it's irrelevant :-) Seriously, pls post the errors!

Comment: I think that problem could be in java version that used in command line, and JRE that is used in Windows

Comment: What is your %PATH% set to when you are in the command window? Please post the output from `C:\>echo %PATH%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the wrong folder. try

```
cd Desktop
```

and call java -jar

I assume that the folder Desktop/fonts exists.

Comment: don't use hard coded path in your programs, due to this you don't have to change path each time. Just change path in properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Your jar can not find the path specified for `fonts\DINOT-Medium.ttf`, Provide correct path and do not use hard coded path in programs. Use properties file for that.

Comment: But how come via double click on jar it finds the path correctly,but not via cmd? I removed all fonts from my app, and now it can`t find my SQL database file that in the same folder

Comment: Show us %PATH% value when in the command window. It may be running a different installed Java. Some software installs a JVM to be used by that software. If it is in your path then simply typing `java` will use that other version. Try typing the full path to your installed java.

Answer (score -2):

.jar is probably not associated with the `java` executable. Check the file type registration entry in your Windows registry or via "Default Programs" in your control panel.

Comment: If it opens on double click the Default Programs are OK.